# Dynamic column width in Flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create three columns grid and I want it to be responsive using Flex. Using the CSS as shown in the fiddle link below I am able to get pretty responsive layout. The problem is that the second column (the blue one) is not getting shrinker when resizing, and instead what happens is that the yellow column is disappering. See the following gif for example:
[Example video](https://uploadfiles.io/v5c0u)

How can I make the blue box getting smaller when resizing so that the yellow box won't disappear?

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
.container-main {
    margin: 50px;   
}

.box-container {
  display:flex;
  //align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: #cccccc;


  align-content: stretch;  

}

.box-tick-code {
    background-color: red;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 40px;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-shrink: 2;
    min-width: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

.box-tick-title {
    background-color:blue;
    display:flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    min-width: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;   

}

.long-title {


  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box-more-info {
    background-color:yellow;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    flex-shrink: 2;
        min-width: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the fiddle link to the HTML/CSS:

[Link to the HTML CSS in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vo5a8tg/1/)

Comment: add `fiddle link`

Comment: Thank you @BhargavChudasama, Added the fiddle link

Comment: Links to js fiddle must be accompanied by the code in the question itself - do not ignore the rules of SO or try to circumvent them by marking text as code

Comment: its working fine as responsive. @SyndicatorBBB

Comment: Thank you @BhargavChudasama .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happen when you remove or don't have **view port meta tag** in your html page or file.
add this to html head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

I guess you don't need to set **(min-height)** and **(min-width)** to (0) if you haven't specified another value before.

here is the snippets is working:

```css
 .container-main {
    margin: 50px;   
}

.box-container {
  display:flex;
  //align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: #cccccc;


  align-content: stretch;  

}

.box-tick-code {
    background-color: red;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 40px;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-shrink: 2;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

.box-tick-title {
    background-color:blue;
    display:flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    min-width: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;   

}

.long-title {
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box-more-info {
    background-color:yellow;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    flex-shrink: 2;
    min-width: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-main">
                <div class="box-container">
                  <div class="box-tick-code">
                    <div class="long-title">title</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-tick-title">
                    <div class="long-title">imagine if there is some title here</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-more-info">
                    <div class="long-title">title</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

My answer is based on Gif example you provide

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB anytime dear.